# Disable <th> $title in Plugin Options Screen?

Tags: plugin-development, settings-api

Is there a way, using the Settings API, to disable the use of the  cell of the table created for options?

The `add_settings_field` 2nd parameter is the `$title` attribute (string) and is required. This string is then placed to the left of the input area for the settings field. This 'indents' the input area.

I put the 'description' of the setting input area after the settings  tag when rendered. Don't need any space to the left of the `<input>` tag.

What are the recommendations for removing that space to the left of the `<input>` tag, using the Settings API in the standard way? For instance, the Settings, Permalinks page has the `<input>` areas at the left edge.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As background, and to answer my own question (after some research), the `<form>` tag in an Options screen is usually generated with code similar to this:

```
<form action='options.php' method='post'>
<?php
settings_fields( 'pluginPage' );    // initializes all of the settings fields
do_settings_sections( 'pluginPage' );   // does the settings section; into a table
submit_button();    // creats the submit button
?>
</form>
```

The `do_settings_section()` function is part of the Options API, and is responsible for creating the option settings fields defined in add_settings_fields statements.  (See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_settings_sections/ ).

The `do_settings_section()` function eventually calls `do_settings_fields()` which outputs (renders) the actual `<input>` statements via the callback specified by `add_settings_field()`. (See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_settings_fields/ ).

If we look at the code for `do_settings_field`, we will find statements that output each settings field (into a table - *sigh*):

```
echo "<tr{$class}>";

if ( ! empty( $field['args']['label_for'] ) ) {
    echo '<th scope="row"><label for="' . esc_attr( $field['args']['label_for'] ) . '">' . $field['title'] . '</label></th>';
} else {
    echo '<th scope="row">' . $field['title'] . '</th>';
}
echo '<td>';
call_user_func($field['callback'], $field['args']);
echo '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
```

And we can see here the `<th>` code for the field `$title` (defined in the `add_settings_field` definition of the settings field).

So, the only way to output settings fields without a table, in the format you want, is to bypass the `do_settings_section()` in the `<form>` with your own code, such as using your own `my_render_fields()` function in the settings form:

```
<form action='options.php' method='post'>
<?php
settings_fields( 'pluginPage' );    // initializes all of the settings fields
my_render_fields();     // render fields without do_settings so no table codes
submit_button();    // creates the submit button
?>
</form>
```

Note that `settings_field()` will also include the 'nonce' in the form, which is needed on Settings pages. (Not having a nonce can cause other errors on settings screens.)

Hope this helps others. Digging into the source code of WP functions sometimes gives you insights into problems. (I was hoping for a filter that would bypass the rendering of the field, but no such luck. But creating your own field rendering function is not hard.)