# WordPress plugin output formatting

Tags: plugins, table, css

I'm currently working on my very first Wordpress plugin, and it is coming along nicely. I do have one question about the formatting of the generated output.

At the moment, the plugin outputs a table with the standings of several teams of a sports-club. So for every team it shows the opponents, their ranking, games played, games won and number of points scored in the games (in Dutch "doelsaldo", but I don't know how to translate that properly...).

I have not added any type of styling to the table or it's cells, figuring that the installed theme should take care of this as much as possible. I am doing the development on a localhost-installation, using the default theme, and it is nice-looking. However, when I installed it to a test-site using a different theme, it is obvious that it lacks a lot of styling.

I'm guessing I'm not the first one that runs into this problem, so I was wondering what is the advised approach for this? Should I abandon the table-tag altogether (though in my opinion, this kind of data is exactly what should be put in a table), or is it advisable to arrange everything with inline-css? Maybe I'm missing another option altogether. I'm just interested in the preferred approach for this since there are literally thousands (if not millions) of different themes out there...

Comment: off-topic about "doesaldo" ;-) https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/doelsaldo

Comment: in your plugin you can add a default stylesheet and in the plugin configuration, you give the possibility to deactivate it (or active it if the stylesheet is deactivated).

Comment: @mmm Do you have an example of this? Sounds interesting!

Comment: for the plugin configuration, read this page : https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API

Comment: @mmm Sorry, I did not mean the configuration. I already figured that out. I meant an example how to add a stylesheet for the front-end output

Comment: use that : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question (and answer) - both mine, related to the formatting of the settings input area.  [Disable <th> $title in Plugin Options Screen?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/306668/disable-th-title-in-plugin-options-screen)

The default is to put settings in a table, with cells for the label, input, and despcription. If you want to have another format (not tables ,perhaps some styling, etc), then take a look at my answer. (Hint: it's related to replacing `do_settings()` in the form with your own field rendering.)

Comment: He's talking about on the front-end though.

Comment: Hmm...I read the original question as being 'how to format the settings area in my plugin options'. Which matches my answer (don't use do_settings(), use your own function when creating the form). His comment (5th one, as I see it) changed the whole question....he's looking for how to add a stylesheet, for which you use wp_enqueue_style, as mentioned in a later comment to the question.